# I need to disorder an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I need disorder an array. I tryed something like this:

```
var letras = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

function disorder(p){

  for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    pos = Math.random()*p.length;
    temp=p[pos];
    p.splice(pos,1);
    p.push(temp);
  }
}
```

But it doesnt work, and I am not sure that was memory efficient because of the deletes.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an integer as index.

```
pos = Math.random() * p.length | 0;
```

> The [bitwise or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR) cast the value to integer.

```js
function disorder(p) {
    var i, pos, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        pos = Math.random() * p.length | 0;
        temp = p[pos];
        p.splice(pos, 1);
        p.push(temp);
    }
}

var letras = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'], p = []

disorder(letras);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(letras, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: awwwrrr, y u no use the double tilde of horror! `~~(Math.random() * p.plength);` :P

Comment: @jAndy, but that needs parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

How about just doing a random sort?

```js
var letras = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

function disorder(arr, entropy){
  var disorderedArr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * entropy); 
  });

  return disorderedArr;
}

var disorderedLetras = disorder(letras, 10);
console.log(disorderedLetras);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(disorderedLetras, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

While probably not statistically vigorous, this will do what you want and gives you some control over how random things actually will be.